# How can I Unit Test This When There's No Public Constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I wrote myself a handy little extension method to use with Directory Services - just put the NT domain with the UserId and concatenate them before passing them on:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> NtUserIds(this ResultPropertyCollection coll)
{        
    var domains = coll[ntDomain].Cast<string>();
    var ids = coll[ntUserID].Cast<string>();
    return domains.Zip(ids, (domain, id) => $"{domain}\\{id}");
}
```

I want to unit test it, but I'm vexed - I can't create a `ResultPropertyCollection` because it doesn't have a `public` constructor.

I was going to Moq it but the indexer returns a `ResultPropertyValueCollection` - which *also* does not have `public` constructor.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. What is your dependency here that you want to (need to) mock?

Comment: I need to create a unit test creates a `ResultPropertyCollection` and calls my extension method to test its functionality - but I can't create a `ResultPropertyCollection` because there's no public constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResultPropertyCollection` does have an [internal parameterless ctor](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/ResultPropertyCollection.cs#L14).

With reflection you can create an instance like this:

```cs
var ctor = typeof(ResultPropertyCollection).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).First();
var instance = (ResultPropertyCollection)ctor.Invoke(null);
```